# Cannot get correct item selection from DropDown widget in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown

In my Kivy app, one of the text inputs triggers the opening of a DropDown widget when `on_focus`. The textinput is part of a custom BoxLayout `IngredientRow` which I dinamically add to the screen on the press of a button.

What I want is to fill the textinput with the text of the button selected from the DropDown. This works for the first `IngredientRow`. However, when I add new rows, selecting an item from the DropDown in a row different from the first, will fill the textinput from the first row. See below a minimal working example:

The py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class DelIngButton(Button):
    pass
class DropListButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DropListButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.parent.parent.select(self.text))
class IngredientRow(BoxLayout):
    pass
class MeasureDropDown(DropDown):
    pass

####################################
class AddWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.DropDown = MeasureDropDown()

    def addIngredient(self, instance): #adds a new IngredientRow
        row = instance.parent
        row.remove_widget(row.children[0])
        row.add_widget(Factory.DelIngButton(), index=0)
        self.ingsGrid.add_widget(Factory.IngredientRow(), index=0)


class WMan(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WMan, self).__init__(**kwargs)

kv = Builder.load_file("ui/layout.kv")

class RecipApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RecipApp().run()
```

and the kv file:

```
#:set text_color 0,0,0,.8

#:set row_height '35sp'

#:set main_padding ['10sp', '10sp']
#:set small_padding ['5sp', '5sp']


<DropListButton>: # Button for custom DropDown
    color: text_color
    background_normal: ''

<DelIngButton>: # Button to delete row
    text: '-'
    size_hint: None, None
    height: row_height
    width: row_height
    on_release: self.parent.parent.remove_widget(self.parent)

<MeasureDropDown>:
    id: dropDown
    DropListButton:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: row_height
        text: "g"
    DropListButton:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: row_height
        text: "Kg"
    TextInput:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: row_height
        hint_text: 'new'

<IngredientRow>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: row_height
    spacing: '5sp'
    TextInput:
        id: ing
        hint_text: 'Ingredient'
        multiline: False
        size_hint: .6, None
        height: row_height
    TextInput:
        id: quant
        hint_text: 'Quantity'
        multiline: False
        size_hint: .2, None
        height: row_height
    TextInput:
        id: measure
        hint_text: 'measure'
        size_hint: .2, None
        height: row_height
        on_focus:
            app.root.ids.add.DropDown.open(self) if self.focus else app.root.ids.add.DropDown.dismiss(self)
            app.root.ids.add.DropDown.bind(on_select=lambda self, x: setattr(app.root.ids.add.ingredientRow.children[1], 'text', x))
    Button:
        id: addIng
        text: "+"
        size_hint: None, None
        height: row_height
        width: row_height
        on_release: app.root.ids.add.addIngredient(self)


<MainScrollView@ScrollView>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']

##################
# Windows
##################

WMan:
    AddWindow:
        id: add

<AddWindow>:
    name: 'add'
    ingsGrid: ingsGrid
    ingredientRow: ingredientRow

    MainScrollView:
        height: self.parent.size[1]
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: main_padding
            StackLayout:
                id: ingsGrid
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                padding: small_padding
                IngredientRow:
                    id: ingredientRow
```

I understand the problem is with the following part of the code:

```
on_select=lambda self, x: setattr(app.root.ids.add.ingredientRow.children[1], 'text', x)
```

as this will always call the first IngredientRow. However, I could not figure out how to refer to the IngredientRow where the DropDown is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining my first answer with code to handle the `TextInput` in the `MeasureDropDown`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class DelIngButton(Button):
    pass


class DropListButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DropListButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.parent.parent.select(self.text))


class DropListTextInput(TextInput):
    # Provides a couple needed behaviors

    def on_focus(self, *args):
        if self.focus:
            self.dropDown.selection_is_DLTI = True
        else:
            self.dropDown.selection_is_DLTI = False

    def on_text_validate(self, *args):
        self.dropDown.selection_is_DLTI = False

        # put the text from this widget into the TextInput that the DropDown is attached to
        self.dropDown.attach_to.text = self.text

        # dismiss the DropDown
        self.dropDown.dismiss()


class IngredientRow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(IngredientRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = MeasureDropDown()

    def handle_focus(self, ti):
        # handle on_focus event for the measure TextInput
        if ti.focus:
            # open DropDown if the TextInput gets focus
            self.dropdown.open(ti)
        else:
            # ti has lost focus
            if self.dropdown.selection_is_DLTI:
                # do not dismiss if a DropListTextInput is the selection
                return

            # dismiss DropDown
            self.dropdown.dismiss(ti)
            self.dropdown.unbind_all()
            self.dropdown.fbind('on_select', lambda self, x: setattr(ti, 'text', x))


class MeasureDropDown(DropDown):
    # set to True if the selection is a DropListTextInput
    selection_is_DLTI = BooleanProperty(False)

    def unbind_all(self):
        for callBack in self.get_property_observers('on_select'):
            self.funbind('on_select', callBack)


####################################
class AddWindow(Screen):

    def addIngredient(self, instance): #adds a new IngredientRow
        row = instance.parent
        row.remove_widget(row.children[0])
        row.add_widget(Factory.DelIngButton(), index=0)
        self.ingsGrid.add_widget(Factory.IngredientRow(), index=0)


class WMan(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WMan, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# kv = Builder.load_file("ui/layout.kv")
kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:set text_color 0,0,0,.8

#:set row_height '35sp'

#:set main_padding ['10sp', '10sp']
#:set small_padding ['5sp', '5sp']


<DropListButton>: # Button for custom DropDown
    color: text_color
    background_normal: ''

<DelIngButton>: # Button to delete row
    text: '-'
    size_hint: None, None
    height: row_height
    width: row_height
    on_release: self.parent.parent.remove_widget(self.parent)

<MeasureDropDown>:
    id: dropDown
    DropListButton:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: row_height
        text: "g"
    DropListButton:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: row_height
        text: "Kg"
    DropListTextInput:  # CustomTextInput instead of standard TextInput
        dropDown: dropDown  # provide easy access to the DropDown
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: row_height
        hint_text: 'new'
        multiline: False  # needed to trigger on_text_validate

<IngredientRow>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: row_height
    spacing: '5sp'
    TextInput:
        id: ing
        hint_text: 'Ingredient'
        multiline: False
        size_hint: .6, None
        height: row_height
    TextInput:
        id: quant
        hint_text: 'Quantity'
        multiline: False
        size_hint: .2, None
        height: row_height
    TextInput:
        id: measure
        hint_text: 'measure'
        size_hint: .2, None
        height: row_height
        on_focus:
            root.handle_focus(self)  # focus event is now handled in the IngredientRow class
    Button:
        id: addIng
        text: "+"
        size_hint: None, None
        height: row_height
        width: row_height
        on_release: app.root.ids.add.addIngredient(self)


<MainScrollView@ScrollView>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']

##################
# Windows
##################

WMan:
    AddWindow:
        id: add

<AddWindow>:
    name: 'add'
    ingsGrid: ingsGrid
    ingredientRow: ingredientRow

    MainScrollView:
        height: self.parent.size[1]
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: main_padding
            StackLayout:
                id: ingsGrid
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                padding: small_padding
                IngredientRow:
                    id: ingredientRow
''')


class RecipApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RecipApp().run()
```

I have added a `DropListTextInput` class for use in the `MeasureDropDown` and added a `handle_focus()` method to the `IngredientRow` class.

I have also added a `selection_is_DLTI` `BooleanProperty` to the `MeasureDropDown` class which keeps track of whether the selected widget is a `DropListTextInput`.

The new `handle_focus()` method does not dismiss the `MeasureDropDown` if the selected widget is a `DropListTextInput`.

The `DropListTextInput` is limited to a single line, so that hitting `Enter` in it will trigger the `on_text_validate()` method, which sets the text in the `measure` `TextInput` and dismisses the `MeasureDropDown`.

I used `Builder.load_string()` just for my own convenience.

Comment: Great! Works as intended, but there is still one bug left. Imagine I have two IngredientRows. If I open the DropDown from the second IngredientRow and, while it is open, I click on the textInput in the first IngredientRow, I get the error: ```kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <RecipApp.ui.widgets.IngredientDropDown object at 0x000001C64C881048> to window, it already has a parent <kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x000001C64CB90828>```. How to solve this? I tried  running ```funbind``` first, but did not work.

Comment: That was my first suggestion in my first answer "One way to fix that would be to create a separate MeasureDropDown for each IngredientRow.".

Comment: I see that could solve the problem, but probably a bit inconvenient given that I do not know a-priori how many rows there will be. What about following the ```fbind``` and ```funbind``` part of your answer? I was thinking that I could solve this simply by setting textinput.on_focus to unbind all the lambda functions first, and then bind to the DropDown, so that this conflict does not occur. However, I did not manage to do so. Would this be possible?

Comment: I have modified my answer to use a separate `MeasureDropDown` for each `IngredientRow`. Modified `IngredientRow` to create a `MeasureDropDown` in its `__init__()` method, and changed `handle_focus()` to use it. Also modified `AddWindow` to no longer create a `MeasureDropDown`.

Comment: amazing, thank you so much! (would you also upvote my questions if you think they can be useful?)

Comment: I'm actually having one more issue with this. I have several textinputs inside a ScrollView. When a 'normal' TextInput is on focus, I can easily scroll the view without losing the focus on the textinput. However, if the textinput opens a ```MeasureDropDown``` widget, scrolling is not possible anymore (resulting in some of dropdown items not to be selectable if they are "hidden" from the current view). How could I solve this?

Comment: I think that should be a separate question posted to stack overflow.

Comment: I have opened a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510256/kivy-textinput-with-dropdown-widget-does-not-allow-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time a `measure` `TextInput` gets focus, another lambda function is added to the `on_select` event of `MeasureDropDown`, and none are ever unbound. That means that every time one of the dropdown choices gets selected, all of those accumulated lambda functions are executed, so each `TextInput` that has ever gotten focus gets its text changed.

One way to fix that would be to create a separate `MeasureDropDown` for each `IngredientRow`.

Another approach is to unbind all the prior lambda functions before binding the current one. Here are some changes to your code that accomplish that:

```
class MeasureDropDown(DropDown):
    def unbind_all(self):
        # unbind all the current call backs for `on_slect`
        for callBack in self.get_property_observers('on_select'):
            self.funbind('on_select', callBack)
```

Then use the `unbind_all()` method in the `kv`:

```
TextInput:
    id: measure
    hint_text: 'measure'
    size_hint: .2, None
    height: row_height
    on_focus:
        app.root.ids.add.DropDown.open(self) if self.focus else app.root.ids.add.DropDown.dismiss(self)
        app.root.ids.add.DropDown.unbind_all()
        app.root.ids.add.DropDown.fbind('on_select', lambda self, x: setattr(root.ids.measure, 'text', x))
```

Note this answer uses `fbind` and `funbind` (`bind` and `unbind` won't work like this).

Comment: amazing, also made me discover fbind, thank you! It works as expected, except the DropDown gets dismissed when I click on the DropDown's textinput (the last item). I see this happens because of ```on_focus:
        app.root.ids.add.DropDown.open(self) if self.focus else app.root.ids.add.DropDown.dismiss(self)``` but cannot figure out how to solve it. I tried something like ```if self.focus or -----.focus```, but how do I refer to that textinput?